# How to get an anonymous phone number to make an account on Tor?

Tags: anonymity, deanonymization, surveillance

I am involved in some activism work against a powerful group that is known to use threats against its opponents. As a result, many activists have been silenced and quit working against said powerful group.

As part of my work, I need to use some online services, which, sadly, requires phone verification. Since my country has mandatory SIM registration laws, even if I access the service through Tor, I will be de-anonymized via my phone number.

What can I do to maintain my anonymity?

Answer (score 0):

This question pops out from time to time and not just regarding Tor. The GSM phone is a beacon and tracking device 2-in-1, so if you need it to be anonymous - just register a SIM for someone else, like offer a hobo some booze to register a SIM for you, it works ;) After that don't forget to maintain the geolocation security procedures, that's it.